# How to pass variables to a theme template file from EntityAPIController::buildContent()

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I may be going about this incorrectly, if so please point me in the right direction.

I currently have a custom entity type and I'm adding the display fields via a controller class that extends EntityAPIController. I want to attach some content from elsewhere (non-entities) to the display of this custom entity.

I have an implementation of `hook_theme`:

```
function module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'module_plugin_instance' => [
    'template' => 'module-plugin-instance',
    'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'variables' => [
        'instance_id' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then, in `EntityTypeController::buildContent()` I have:

```
$buildContent['module_plugin_instance_' . $instance_id] = [
  '#theme' => 'module_plugin_instance'
];
```

Where I'm failing is I can't figure out how to pass variables to the theme template here.  The dummy html I'm putting in the template renders fine, just no variables.  I've tried several different things, but I can't seem to get `$instance_id` to my template - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide theme variables through properties, e.g.:

```
$buildContent['module_plugin_instance_' . $instance_id] = [
  '#theme' => 'module_plugin_instance',
  '#instance_id' => 'foo',
];
```